# PHP PDO ODBC - The data types are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: php, sql, pdo, odbc

I don't seem to be able to get a simple WHERE clause with a parameter to work, I am constantly getting an error message saying:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. (SQLExecute[402] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)
```

I have tried this query in multiple different ways, e.g.

Unnamed:

```
$query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM bksb_Resources WHERE ResourceType = ?");
$query->execute( array('assessment') );
```

Unnamed and using bindValue setting it to string

```
$query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM bksb_Resources WHERE ResourceType = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, 'assessment', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute(  );
```

Named and using bindParam to set it to string:

```
$val = 'assessment';
$query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM bksb_Resources WHERE ResourceType = :myp");
$query->bindParam(':myp', $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute(  );
```

But no matter how I do it, I always get this error message.

The column in question is of type: varchar(max), so presumably it is assuming the parameter being sent is of type 'text' even when I specify it to be a string value (char, varchar)

I can't change the database as it's for another piece of software.

What is the way around this? I really do not want to have to CAST every single time I do a where clause like this (or is that what everyone does?).

Thank you.

Comment: Having the same issue... did you figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried `"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM bksb_Resources WHERE ResourceType LIKE ?"˙` ? If you don't use the wildcards, it will function almost identically as `=`.

Answer (score 5):

We had an issue similar to this, and in our case we had the following in our `/etc/odbc.ini` file:

```
[ServerAlias]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = 1.2.3.4
PORT = 1433
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

We discovered that if you change the `TDS_Version` to `7.2` all of our bind queries started working correctly.

```
[ServerAlias]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = 1.2.3.4
PORT = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.2
```

I'm not sure on the reason for this, but I suspect it is probably documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change field type to CHAR o VARCHAR? (and not VARCHAR(MAX) that have this type of incompatibility).

Or have you tried to convert data types?

```
$val = 'assessment';
$query = $DBH->prepare(
    "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM bksb_Resources WHERE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, ResourceType) = :myp");
$query->bindParam(':myp', $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

I'm sorry but I don't have MS SQL Server to test the code, but I get that tip from this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms176089.aspx

Note that warning:

> Code page translations are supported for char and varchar data types,
>   but not for text data type. As with earlier versions of SQL Server,
>   data loss during code page translations is not reported.

Hope it helps!